# Is there an easy way to use a small script to automate reading of a text file and plotting using bash script with awk or other unix commands?

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, sed

I'm new to using awk and manipulation of text files. I have model output files consisting of >600,000 lines. I want to use in a bash script for automating plotting of x,y points from this file. I use "t" to denote time and "T" to denote temperature, which are x and y respectively. Each row or line has a different number of t-T points

Each line consists of the following separated by spaces shown as commas here:

-loglikelihood, -posterior, #Npairs-1, t1, T1, t2, T2 ...

Is there a way to use a script to start reading the file at "CHAIN" and reading until "CHAIN END" is reached in the file? Each t,T pair from each row needs to be plotted as x,y pairs individually, so all t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, etc. are all the X-values and T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, etc, are all the Y-values.

so for example, if a row or single line looked like this:
-400, -430, 3, 500, 50, 350, 100, 200, 20, 0, 5

---- then the 500, 350, 100, 200, and 0 are all X (time) points and the rest are the Y (temperature) points (i.e., 50, 100, 20, 5). Therefore 500, 350 is the first x,y pair and so on...

Bonus: I would like to keep the log likelihood value of -400 for each row and associated set of points to then normalize the entire group of 600,000 t-T 'paths' from 0-1 for plotting using a color ramp.

Actual data file *** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DLabBKWbhaX-w4Kp5jxdiuL5afDFZmuX/view?usp=sharing***

update: I had originally thought transposing to columns would work, but that may be difficult and inefficient, since not only would rows be transposed to columns but the pairs of time-temperature points would need to be split up into two columns per every row read in and all placed side-by-side to be read in correctly

Comment: Where does `-469.781525` come from? It would be easier to read, when your example input and output are without the decimals and perhaps less fields on a line.

Comment: The -469 is a log likelihood value that is output (along with all other values) from a larger model output file. I thought providing actual values would be more useful?

Comment: I am trying to understand the requirements. A part of the example input line is `3 475.105835 48.555820 135.366699 23.822214 58.519234 83.969536`, what do you want? You wrote 3 is the number of pairs minus 1, so it looks like you want 2 pairs from this line: `475.105835 48.555820 135.366699 23.822214`. Did I understand that good, let me see what output you want from this line. No, something completely different. Make it simple!

Comment: Perhaps an example as `500001 foo1 foo2 3 12:00 40 12:15 48 12:30 45 foo3 foo4 foo5`.

Comment: I've tried editing to make it simpler and more clear. This is a fairly complex operation and hard to describe succinctly. It is cutting 600,000 rows (variable number of values in each line) and then taking each row and splitting into 2 columns of 'time' and 'temperature' as x,y for plotting

Comment: Show an inputline and outputline that are related to each other. Now I don't know how I should look at `475.105835`. Is that a pair t.T, separated by a dot, or is it a time field, or is it the likehood value? Alternatively, you can show some real data (2 rows) and explain with both input and output like `logL, t1, T1, t2, T3` and explain why you don't have T2 and t3.

Comment: we really need to see some actual data (eg, a few input lines with 3-4 sets of time/temps), the associated (desired) output; also, your `awk` references `$2` and then `$5` ... why skip `$3` and `$4` (doesn't make sense from your sample input of `logL, t1, T1, t2, T2` ...?? the sample screen shot (you need to convert that to textual data and add to the question) shows 4 columns of ouput ... do you want 2 columns or 4 columns?

Comment: How many columns are there?

Comment: see the linked file

Answer (score 0):

partial answer, perhaps it will provide some hints for the final solution...

you can create the columnar format with a simply change

```
$ awk 'NR>=45&& NR<=600044 {for(i=5;i<=19;i+=2) print $i,$(i+1)}' input.txt > output.txt
```

this will drop the likelihood value since it doesn't appear in the output.  Next challenge is splitting one pair of columns to multiple column format. If I understood it right, there will be 600,000 x 2 = 1.2M columns in the final output.